# How do I create multiple scheduled notifications each on specific days of the week and time

Tags: java, android, notifications

I need to create multiple notifications that each have a certain day of the week to display at a certain time. E.g. Every Monday at 8pm and when the notification is clicked it should go to a activity in my application. I also have a settings activity where the user can choose which notifications they want to show or not.

I have looked at loads of examples and even android docs but haven't figured out a way to get this working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Exact times might be quite difficult due the the different restrictions on background processing by the system. But a satisfactory solution might be to use alarm manager.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#examples-of-real-time-clock-alarms

Taken from the above docs

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 24 hours.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, alarmIntent);
```

You'll have to create and register the AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{    
    public AlarmReceiver (){}

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         doSomething();
    }
}
```

Register receiver somewhere in activity

```
private AlarmReceiver receiver = new AlarmReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, new IntentFilter());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure where these code snippets go, is it a class, main activity etc. Can you please guide me into the right direction